# MongoDB Atlas Golang mgo package "No reachable servers" error

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

I continuously get the following error when attempting to connect to my MongoDB Atlas database.

```
no reachable servers
exit status 1
```

I am running MongoDB version 3.4, which is compatible with mgo.
I have whitelisted all IP addresses on MongoDB Atlas, including my own.
I have created a user named `'root'` on MongoDB Atlas with admin rights.
I am running on Ubuntu 18.04, and I have set my DNS Nameserver to 8.8.8.8.
I am using the Community supported version of `mgo` from `github.com/globalsign/mgo`.
My code is as follows:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "github.com/globalsign/mgo"
    "github.com/globalsign/mgo/bson"
)

func main() {
    database := "bookstore"
    collection := "books"
    user := "root"
    pword := "root"
    url := "mongodb://" + user + ":" + pword + "@<prefix>.mongodb.net:27017/" + database + "?w=majority"

    session, err := mgo.Dial(url)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    } else {
                fmt.Println("Success.")
        }
}
```

I have looked at the following questions.  These do not solve my problem:
[CreateSession: no reachable servers - mgo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43537470/createsession-no-reachable-servers-mgo)
[How to solve panic: no reachable servers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37430510/how-to-solve-panic-no-reachable-servers)
[Connecting to MongoDB Atlas using Golang mgo: Persistent no reachable server to replica set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41173720/connecting-to-mongodb-atlas-using-golang-mgo-persistent-no-reachable-server-to)
[Golang / MGO -- panic: no reachable servers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20976030/golang-mgo-panic-no-reachable-servers)
[No reachable servers on static linked go binary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49287039/no-reachable-servers-on-static-linked-go-binary)
[Go and MongoDB connection won't work with panic log "no reachable server"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46757753/go-and-mongodb-connection-wont-work-with-panic-log-no-reachable-server)
[No reachable servers on static linked go binary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49287039/no-reachable-servers-on-static-linked-go-binary/49304794#49304794)
[How to use new URL from mongodb 3.6 to connect from golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52052311/how-to-use-new-url-from-mongodb-3-6-to-connect-from-golang/52068597#52068597)
[How to connect to remote Mongodb server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50771414/how-to-connect-to-remote-mongodb-server)
Any help is truly appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure your MongoDB Atlas cluster is running v3.4 ?

Comment: Yes, running v3. 4

Answer (score 2):

One issue is the [MongoDB Connection String URI](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/) that you're using to connect to the [Atlas](https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/atlas) cluster.

There are two types of MongoDB connection string format:

- [Standard Connection String Format](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/#standard-connection-string-format)
- [DNS Seedlist Connection Format](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/#connections-dns-seedlist)

The DNS seedlist format is shorter because it leverages discovery of available servers using DNS. In order to leverage the DNS seedlist, use a connection string prefix of `mongodb+srv:` rather than the standard `mongodb:`.

Based on your posted snippet, it seems that you're mixing the two formats. If you're trying to use the DNS seedlist format, you need to specify `mongodb+srv:`, if you're trying to use the standard format, you need to specify the other hosts. For example:

```
"mongodb://FOO-shard-00-00-BAR.mongodb.net:27017,FOO-shard-00-01-BAR.mongodb.net:27017,FOO-shard-00-02-BAR.mongodb.net:27017/test?replicaSet=FOO-shard-0"
```

On that note, you're also using [globalsign/mgo](https://github.com/globalsign/mgo) driver. Currently, it does not support the DNS seedlist format, see [globalsign/mgo/issues#112](https://github.com/globalsign/mgo/issues/112). Also, `globalsign/mgo` currently only has experimental support for MongoDB v4.0+.

You can try to use [mongo-go-driver](https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo) instead if you're intending to use the DNS seedlist connection format, and/or using MongoDB v3.6+ (At the moment latest version of MongoDB is v4.2)

Comment: Thank you.  I have upvoted your response but I don't have 15 reputation yet.

Comment: If this solved your issue you should accept as answer instead of upvote.